# How can I mount a removable USB drive in WSL?

Tags: mount, windows, usb-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I've gone through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) tutorial and have gotten USBIPD up and running on Windows 11 and the Ubuntu WSL container. Now, how can I *mount* a USB Mass Storage Device in WSL so that File Explorer can see and access it? The USB is formatted as ext4. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that guide is for other kinds of USB devices like SD cards. For mounting disks, including external USB disks I think you want [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/wsl/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux#mounting-drvfs). Refer to the section "Mounting DrvFs". The following example uses the Windows `D:` drive.

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

I've never used it for ext4 but see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks! But that guide seems to only help mount Windows drives which have a letter assigned to them. USB drives formatted in ext4 don't have a letter assigned by Windows. Heck, they don't even show up in File Explorer.